# Tensorflow Keras - Error while stacking LSTM layers

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have the following sequence of layers. Adding additional LSTMs in the mix yields the following error which I cannot really understand.

I'm using python 3.7.3 on Linux Ubuntu x64
GCC 7.4.0
tensorflow-gpu='2.0.0'

```py
print(x_train_uni.shape) # (299980, 20, 1)
simple_lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=x_train_uni.shape[-2:]),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16),  
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh')
])

simple_lstm_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
```

which yields:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-32-ba40f416ca84> in <module>
      6     tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16),
      7     tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8),
----> 8     tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh')
      9 ])
     10 

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in __init__(self, layers, name)
    112       tf_utils.assert_no_legacy_layers(layers)
    113       for layer in layers:
--> 114         self.add(layer)
    115 
    116   @property

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/training/tracking/base.py in _method_wrapper(self, *args, **kwargs)
    455     self._self_setattr_tracking = False  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    456     try:
--> 457       result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
    458     finally:
    459       self._self_setattr_tracking = previous_value  # pylint: disable=protected-access

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/sequential.py in add(self, layer)
    194       # If the model is being built continuously on top of an input layer:
    195       # refresh its output.
--> 196       output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
    197       if len(nest.flatten(output_tensor)) != 1:
    198         raise TypeError('All layers in a Sequential model '

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/layers/recurrent.py in __call__(self, inputs, initial_state, constants, **kwargs)
    621 
    622     if initial_state is None and constants is None:
--> 623       return super(RNN, self).__call__(inputs, **kwargs)
    624 
    625     # If any of `initial_state` or `constants` are specified and are Keras

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/base_layer.py in __call__(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs)
    810         # are casted, not before.
    811         input_spec.assert_input_compatibility(self.input_spec, inputs,
--> 812                                               self.name)
    813         graph = backend.get_graph()
    814         with graph.as_default(), backend.name_scope(self._name_scope()):

~/.pyenv/versions/3.7.3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    175                          'expected ndim=' + str(spec.ndim) + ', found ndim=' +
    176                          str(ndim) + '. Full shape received: ' +
--> 177                          str(x.shape.as_list()))
    178     if spec.max_ndim is not None:
    179       ndim = x.shape.ndims

ValueError: Input 0 of layer lstm_19 is incompatible with the layer: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2. Full shape received: [None, 128]
```

If however I change the model like so it actually works.

```
simple_lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=x_train_uni.shape[-2:]),
#     tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64),
#     tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32),
#     tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
#     tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16),  
#     tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh')
])

simple_lstm_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
```

What is that I'm missing? Why two or multiple LSTM layers cannot be stacked one on top of another?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

LSTM layer requires as an input sequence. However, the default setting in Keras is to return final scalar.

Hence second LSTM in proposed architecture is feed with scalar instead of required sequence.

The solution is to use `return_sequences=True` flag (see [LSTM arguments in docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM#arguments)):

```py
import tensorflow as tf

x_train_uni = tf.zeros((100, 20, 1))

simple_lstm_model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(128, input_shape=x_train_uni.shape[-2:], return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(32, return_sequences=True),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.25),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(16, return_sequences=True),  
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(8),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='tanh')
])

simple_lstm_model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mae')
```